# GWT JSONParser.parseStrict

Tags: gwt, json

I have been using `JSONParser`'s parse method without many issues.

Recently, I decided to pay attention to a deprecation notice that I had been seeing. It recommended that I use either `parseStrict` or `parseLenient`.

So, I decided to try out `parseStrict`.

I declared a json string...

```
String jsonstr = "{value : [12,34],[56,78]]}";
```

...I confirmed that it worked with good old `parse`...

```
JSONValue jsv = JSONParser.parse(jsonstr);
```

...and an alert window tells me value of jsv was this:

```
{"value" : [12,34],[56,78]]}
```

Then I used `parseStrict` on the same string:

```
JSONValue jsv = JSONParser.parseStrict(jsonstr);
```

But my GWT app crashed with an exception!

What are the requirements in using `parseStrict` (vs `parse`)? Wny did it trip on such a simple little json string?

```
Uncaught exception escaped
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:129)
......
at com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONParser.evaluate(JSONParser.java)
at com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:218)
at com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONParser.parseStrict(JSONParser.java:87)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the strictest sense, the JSON you've provided just isn't strictly correct.

JSON key values should be surrounded by double quotes [as described in the JSON spec](http://www.json.org/), so your example JSON should be as follows:

```
String jsonstr = "{\"value\" : [[12,34],[56,78]]}";
```

Also, it appears that your braces (`[]`) don't match up (which I have also corrected).

In summary, it could be either the missing matching brace, or the lack of double quotes. To find out, you can wrap the offending code in a try / catch block and do as the stack trace suggests. Namely, call the `getCauses` method on the exception:

```
try {
    JSONValue jsv = JSONParser.parseStrict(jsonstr);
} catch (UmbrellaException e) {
    Set causes = e.getCauses();
    //actually find out what the problem was
}
```

*Note: `JSONParser.parse` just [uses `eval` under the hood](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONParser.html) so be careful when using it!*

Comment: The square bracket mismatch is typo. In my code, there is no bracket mismatch. Typo occurred in typing into this question. So many brackets in JSON!